# Unable to start debugging on the web server [Enterprise Library 3.1]

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-config, enterprise-library, dbconnection

Am migrating a system.

Just framework

The new EntepriseLibrary system is 3.1

The system used the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpiseLibrary.Configuration but this lib does not exist in the new version 3.1.

How to set WebConfig?

- I changed the way the application accesses the database
  Eg .: SqlConnection to DbConnection

WebConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**************"/>
    </configSections> [...]

    <enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings applicationName="Application" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/practices/enterpriselibrary/08-31-2004/configuration">
        <configurationSections>
            <configurationSection xsi:type="ReadOnlyConfigurationSectionData" name="dataConfiguration" encrypt="false">
                <storageProvider xsi:type="XmlFileStorageProviderData" name="XML File Storage Provider" path="dataConfiguration.config"/>
                <dataTransformer xsi:type="XmlSerializerTransformerData" name="Xml Serializer Transformer">
                    <includeTypes/>
                </dataTransformer>
            </configurationSection>
        </configurationSections>
        <keyAlgorithmStorageProvider xsi:nil="true"/>
        <includeTypes/>
    </enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings>
</configuration>
```

DataConfiguration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataConfiguration>
  <xmlSerializerSection type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*************">
    <enterpriseLibrary.databaseSettings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" defaultInstance="Database Instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/practices/enterpriselibrary/08-31-2004/data">
      <databaseTypes>
        <databaseType name="Sql Server" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*************"/>
      </databaseTypes>
      <instances>
        <instance name="Database Instance" type="Sql Server" connectionString="Sql Connection String" />
      </instances>
      <connectionStrings>
        <connectionString name="Sql Connection String">
          <parameters>
           [...]
          </parameters>
        </connectionString>
      </connectionStrings>s
    </enterpriseLibrary.databaseSettings>
  </xmlSerializerSection>
</dataConfiguration>
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you take out the Entlib configuration from your .config?
Do you use the EntLib Config tool for configuration?